# Maximum float value in 10-bit image in WIC

Tags: winapi, nvidia, direct2d, wic, hdr

I'm trying to convert a HDR image float array I load to a 10-bit DWORD with WIC.

The type of the loading file is GUID_WICPixelFormat128bppPRGBAFloat and I got an array of 4 floats per color.

When I try to convert these to 10 bit as follows:

```
struct RGBX
{
    unsigned int b : 10;
    unsigned int g : 10;
    unsigned int r : 10;
    int a : 2;
} rgbx;
```

(which is the format requested by the NVIDIA encoding library for 10-bit rgb),

then I assume I have to divide each of the floats by 1024.0f in order to get them inside the 10 bits of a DWORD.

However, I notice that some of the floats are > 1, which means that their range is not [0,1] as it happens when the image is 8 bit.

What would their range be? How to store a floating point color into a 10-bits integer?

I'm trying to use the NVidia's HDR encoder which requires an ARGB10 like the above structure.

How is the 10 bit information of a color stored as a floating point number?

Btw I tried to convert with WIC but conversion from GUID_WICPixelFormat128bppPRGBAFloat to GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppR10G10B10A2 fails.

```
HRESULT ConvertFloatTo10(const float* f, int wi, int he, std::vector<DWORD>& out)
    {
        CComPtr<IWICBitmap> b;
        wbfact->CreateBitmapFromMemory(wi, he, GUID_WICPixelFormat128bppPRGBAFloat, wi * 16, wi * he * 16, (BYTE*)f, &b);
        CComPtr<IWICFormatConverter> wf;
        wbfact->CreateFormatConverter(&wf);
        wf->Initialize(b, GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppR10G10B10A2, WICBitmapDitherTypeNone, 0, 0, WICBitmapPaletteTypeCustom);

// This last call fails with 0x88982f50 : The component cannot be found. 
}
```

Edit: I found a paper (https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01704278/document), is this relevant to this question?

Comment: I believe the final 4 arguments to the `Initialize()` call on the format converter should only be used when you aren't reducing the bit-depth in the conversion. However, you are reducing the bit-depth, so those parameters suddenly become meaningful, and you cannot simply drop the don't-care quadruple.

Comment: @IInspectable okay but the error value doesn't indicate an invalid parameter, also I tried with various combinations, maybe I try again.

Comment: This exact conversion is not supported by existing built-in (Windows 10) WIC converters. I have dumped all possible conversions here https://pastebin.com/raw/3RE2nvvu (using this C# interop project https://github.com/smourier/WicNet if you want to test on your machine). The closest you can get to is GUID_WICPixelFormat128bppRGBAFloat to GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppRGBA1010102XR or GUID_WICPixelFormat64bppRGBA to GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppRGBA1010102 (not sure if NVidia expects GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppR10G10B10A2 or GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppRGBA1010102,)

Comment: @SimonMourier nvidia expects the structure I posted in the topic. I tried doing the XR version and it succeeds, but the mapping is not correct. I also haven't found any resourceo online on how to convert the floating point array to the 10-bit integer manually... any clues?

Comment: @SimonMourier Btw what's the difference between GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppRGBA1010102  and GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppR10G10B10A2 ?

Comment: I found this: https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01704278/document, is it somehow relevant?

Comment: The difference between the two formats is GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppRGBA1010102 has red in LSB while GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppR10G10B10A2 has red in MSB (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wic/-wic-codec-native-pixel-formats#packed-bit-pixel-formats). For the conversion it's the usual RGB => ScRGB (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wic/-wic-codec-native-pixel-formats#color-space) but using 1023 (10 bits) instead of 255 for normalization. Example here https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/blob/main/src/Microsoft.DotNet.Wpf/src/PresentationCore/System/Windows/Media/Color.cs#L1041

Comment: ... which implements this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB ("From sRGB to CIE XYZ"). I have also added example to my github code https://github.com/smourier/WicNet/blob/main/WicNet.Tests/Program.cs#L37

Comment: According to [RGB/BGR Pixel formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wic/-wic-codec-native-pixel-formats#rgbbgr-pixel-formats), It seems RGBA are saved as 128 Bits Per Pixel as Float Where each 32 bits represents a channel. A Possible evidence is [How to: Initialize a Texture From a File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/overviews-direct3d-11-resources-textures-how-to) which states `GUID_WICPixelFormat128bppRGBAFloat` is equivalence of `DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floating-point color content that is greater than the 0..1 range is High Dynamic Range (HDR) content. If you trivially convert it to 10:10:10:2 UNORM then you are using 'clipping' for values over 1. This doesn't give good results.

## SDR 10:10:10 or 8:8:8

You should instead use [tone-mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tone_mapping) which converts the HDR signal to a SDR (Standard Dynamic Range a.k.a. 0..1) before or as part of doing the conversion to 10:10:10:2.

There a many different approaches to tone-mapping, but a common 'generic' solution is the *Reinhard tone-mapping operator*. Here's an implementation using [DirectXTex](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTex).

```
std::unique_ptr<ScratchImage> timage(new (std::nothrow) ScratchImage);
if (!timage)
{
    wprintf(L"\nERROR: Memory allocation failed\n");
    return 1;
}

// Compute max luminosity across all images
XMVECTOR maxLum = XMVectorZero();
hr = EvaluateImage(image->GetImages(), image->GetImageCount(), image->GetMetadata(),
    [&](const XMVECTOR* pixels, size_t w, size_t y)
    {
        UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(y);

        for (size_t j = 0; j < w; ++j)
        {
            static const XMVECTORF32 s_luminance = { { { 0.3f, 0.59f, 0.11f, 0.f } } };

            XMVECTOR v = *pixels++;

            v = XMVector3Dot(v, s_luminance);

            maxLum = XMVectorMax(v, maxLum);
        }
    });
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    wprintf(L" FAILED [tonemap maxlum] (%08X%ls)\n", static_cast<unsigned int>(hr), GetErrorDesc(hr));
    return 1;
}

maxLum = XMVectorMultiply(maxLum, maxLum);

hr = TransformImage(image->GetImages(), image->GetImageCount(), image->GetMetadata(),
    [&](XMVECTOR* outPixels, const XMVECTOR* inPixels, size_t w, size_t y)
    {
        UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(y);

        for (size_t j = 0; j < w; ++j)
        {
            XMVECTOR value = inPixels[j];

            const XMVECTOR scale = XMVectorDivide(
                XMVectorAdd(g_XMOne, XMVectorDivide(value, maxLum)),
                XMVectorAdd(g_XMOne, value));
            const XMVECTOR nvalue = XMVectorMultiply(value, scale);

            value = XMVectorSelect(value, nvalue, g_XMSelect1110);

            outPixels[j] = value;
        }
    }, *timage);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    wprintf(L" FAILED [tonemap apply] (%08X%ls)\n", static_cast<unsigned int>(hr), GetErrorDesc(hr));
    return 1;
}
```

## HDR10

***UPDATE***: If you are trying to convert HDR floating-point content to an "HDR10" signal, then you need to do:

- Color-space rotate from Rec.709 or P3D65 to Rec.2020.
- Normalize for 'paper white' / 10,000 nits.
- Apply the ST.2084 gamma curve.
- Quantize to 10-bit.

```
// HDTV to UHDTV (Rec.709 color primaries into Rec.2020)
const XMMATRIX c_from709to2020 =
{
    0.6274040f, 0.0690970f, 0.0163916f, 0.f,
    0.3292820f, 0.9195400f, 0.0880132f, 0.f,
    0.0433136f, 0.0113612f, 0.8955950f, 0.f,
    0.f,        0.f,        0.f,        1.f
};

// DCI-P3-D65 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DCI-P3 to UHDTV (DCI-P3-D65 color primaries into Rec.2020)
const XMMATRIX c_fromP3D65to2020 =
{
    0.753845f, 0.0457456f, -0.00121055f, 0.f,
    0.198593f, 0.941777f,   0.0176041f,  0.f,
    0.047562f, 0.0124772f,  0.983607f,   0.f,
    0.f,       0.f,         0.f,         1.f
};

// Custom Rec.709 into Rec.2020
const XMMATRIX c_fromExpanded709to2020 = 
{
    0.6274040f, 0.0457456f, -0.00121055f, 0.f,
    0.3292820f, 0.941777f,   0.0176041f,  0.f,
    0.0433136f, 0.0124772f,  0.983607f,   0.f,
    0.f,        0.f,         0.f,         1.f
};

inline float LinearToST2084(float normalizedLinearValue)
{
    const float ST2084 = pow((0.8359375f + 18.8515625f * pow(abs(normalizedLinearValue), 0.1593017578f)) / (1.0f + 18.6875f * pow(abs(normalizedLinearValue), 0.1593017578f)), 78.84375f);
    return ST2084;  // Don't clamp between [0..1], so we can still perform operations on scene values higher than 10,000 nits
}

// You can adjust this up to 10000.f
float paperWhiteNits = 200.f;

hr = TransformImage(image->GetImages(), image->GetImageCount(), image->GetMetadata(),
    [&](XMVECTOR* outPixels, const XMVECTOR* inPixels, size_t w, size_t y)
    {
        UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(y);

        const XMVECTOR paperWhite = XMVectorReplicate(paperWhiteNits);

        for (size_t j = 0; j < w; ++j)
        {
            XMVECTOR value = inPixels[j];

            XMVECTOR nvalue = XMVector3Transform(value, c_from709to2020);
// Some people prefer the look of using c_fromP3D65to2020
// or c_fromExpanded709to2020 instead.

            // Convert to ST.2084
            nvalue = XMVectorDivide(XMVectorMultiply(nvalue, paperWhite), c_MaxNitsFor2084);

            XMFLOAT4A tmp;
            XMStoreFloat4A(&tmp, nvalue);

            tmp.x = LinearToST2084(tmp.x);
            tmp.y = LinearToST2084(tmp.y);
            tmp.z = LinearToST2084(tmp.z);

            nvalue = XMLoadFloat4A(&tmp);

            value = XMVectorSelect(value, nvalue, g_XMSelect1110);

            outPixels[j] = value;
        }
    }, *timage);
```

> You should really take a look at [texconv](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTex/blob/main/Texconv/texconv.cpp).

## Reference

Reinhard et al., "Photographic tone reproduction for digital images", *ACM Transactions on Graphics*, Volume 21, Issue 3 (July 2002). [ACM DL](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/566654.566575).

Comment: If I am converting the signal to SDR, then what is the point of using the Nvidia 10 bit encoder anyway? The idea is to create a HDR video, not to tonemap a HDR signal to SDR. Unless the Nvidia encoder cannot create HDR video anyway, I guess.

Comment: Updated answer for HDR10 signal prep. I didn't get that was the context here.

Answer (score 0):

@ChuckWalbourn answer is helpful, however I don't want to tonemap to [0,1] as there is no point in tonemapping to SDR then going to 10-bit HDR.

What I 'd think it's correct is to scale to [0,4] instead by first using `g_XMFour`.

```
            const XMVECTOR scale = XMVectorDivide(
                XMVectorAdd(g_XMFour, XMVectorDivide(v, maxLum)),
                XMVectorAdd(g_XMFour, v));
```

then using a specialized 10-bit store which scales by 255 instead of 1023:

```
void XMStoreUDecN4a(DirectX::PackedVector::XMUDECN4* pDestination,DirectX::FXMVECTOR V)
{
    using namespace DirectX;
    XMVECTOR N;
    static const XMVECTOR  Scale = { 255.0f, 255.0f, 255.0f, 3.0f };
    assert(pDestination);
    N = XMVectorClamp(V, XMVectorZero(), g_XMFour);
    N = XMVectorMultiply(N, Scale);
    pDestination->v = ((uint32_t)DirectX::XMVectorGetW(N) << 30) |
        (((uint32_t)DirectX::XMVectorGetZ(N) & 0x3FF) << 20) |
        (((uint32_t)DirectX::XMVectorGetY(N) & 0x3FF) << 10) |
        (((uint32_t)DirectX::XMVectorGetX(N) & 0x3FF));
}
```

And then a specialized 10-bit load which divides with 255 instead of 1023:

```
DirectX::XMVECTOR XMLoadUDecN4a(DirectX::PackedVector::XMUDECN4* pSource)
{
    using namespace DirectX;
    fourx vectorOut;

    uint32_t Element;

    Element = pSource->v & 0x3FF;
    vectorOut.r = (float)Element / 255.f;
    Element = (pSource->v >> 10) & 0x3FF;
    vectorOut.g = (float)Element / 255.f;
    Element = (pSource->v >> 20) & 0x3FF;
    vectorOut.b = (float)Element / 255.f;
    vectorOut.a = (float)(pSource->v >> 30) / 3.f;

    const DirectX::XMVECTORF32 j = { vectorOut.r,vectorOut.g,vectorOut.b,vectorOut.a };
    return j;
}
```